# Folder won't show up in Git but is not ignored

Tags: git, zend-framework, github

I have a folder called `modules` in my project (a Zend 1.12.3 project). The path is `application\modules`. Everything in the application directory commits just fine and shows up in Git, apart from the `modules` directory. It's not ignored by the project's `.gitignore` file:

```
public/styles/.sass-cache
```

Nor is it being ignored by my global `.gitignore` file:

```
.idea
app/logs/*
web/uploads/*
workspace.xml
```

Does anyone have any idea why the modules folder isn't showing up in the directory? This is really annoying since modules are an integral part of Zend...

Comment: git does not add empty folders

Comment: have a look on this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and the generated module indeed only has empty directories so far. Adding files to it makes it show up in Git. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution: the Api module that was generated had the directory structure but no files in it yet, which caused it to not get picked up by Git.